# How to prepare conjoint data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a question regarding the manipulation of my data in R. I am analyzing conjoint data and need to manipulate my choice variable to fit a given standard. Below is how my dataframe currently looks per respondent.

However to use it with the package 'ChoiceModelR' I need to change it so that it looks like in the second table. Currently the Choice variable is a binary variable indicating which  alternative has been selected. In the required format the choice variable is always shown in the first row of a new question an refers to which alternative has been selected. When alternative 2 was selected in question 1, the choice variable will be 2 on the first row of question 1. If alternative 2 has been selected in question 2, the choice variable will be 1 on the first row of question 1. The second row of a question will always be 0 in this case.

The required format is given as the second table below.

Is there an easy way to code this in R?

My current data:

```
|   | ID | Question | Alternative | Choice | X_1 | X_2 | X_3 | X_4 | X_5 | X_6 | X_7 |
|---|----|----------|-------------|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|   | 1  | 1        | 1           | 0      | 2   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 1        | 2           | 1      | 2   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 2        | 1           | 1      | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 2        | 2           | 0      | 2   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 3        | 1           | 0      | 2   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 3        | 2           | 1      | 1   | 2   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 2   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 4        | 1           | 0      | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 4        | 2           | 1      | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 5        | 1           | 1      | 2   | 1   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 2   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 5        | 2           | 0      | 2   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
```

How it has to look:

```
|   | ID | Question | Alternative | Choice | X_1 | X_2 | X_3 | X_4 | X_5 | X_6 | X_7 |
|---|----|----------|-------------|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|   | 1  | 1        | 1           | 2      | 2   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 1        | 2           | 0      | 2   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 2        | 1           | 1      | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 2        | 2           | 0      | 2   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 3        | 1           | 2      | 2   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 3        | 2           | 0      | 1   | 2   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 2   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 4        | 1           | 2      | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 4        | 2           | 0      | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 2   |
|   | 1  | 5        | 1           | 1      | 2   | 1   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 2   | 1   |
|   | 1  | 5        | 2           | 0      | 2   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
```

**UPDATE 14th of JUNE 2020**

In case anyone runs into the same problem I have found a way to format the data correctly. The code I have used is displayed below.

```
choice <- rep(0, nrow(your_df)) #your_df is your dataframe, creates a vector of 0's that is the length of your_df. 
choice[your_df[,"alternative"]==1] <- your_df[your_df[,"choice"]==1,"alternative"] # formats the data in the correct way
new_df <- cbind(your_df, choice) #merges your_df and choice
new+df = subset(new_df, select = -c(selected)) # remove the original selected column
```

Comment: Is the Choice column in your second table correct? 

From the first table, for question 1, the Alternative chosen is 2 (because Choice = 1 for Alternative = 2, and Choice= 0 for Alternative = 1). 

Therefore the second table should have Choice = 0 for Alternative = 1 and Choice = 2 for Alternative = 1) . As of now it is ordered the other way.

Comment: I’ll check your suggestion as soon as I’m near my computer. However I’m fairly sure it has to be this way to be able to be used wirh the package ‘ChoiceModelR’. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sure! If what I said in the previous comment is the correct way of organizing your data, then your solution is pretty easy. Let us know.

Comment: Dear Prasanna, I've read the package manual again and it needs to be in the format as I described. I wasn't able to automate Matt's answer below for a large dataset. Perhaps you have an answer in mind which is easily applied to a large datset?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to transform the data in the way that you'd like, though it's hard to understand your exact conditions:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Question) %>% 
  mutate(Choice = 
           case_when(
             Question %in% c(1, 3, 4) & Alternative == 2 ~ 2,
             Question %in% c(2,5) & Alternative == 2 ~ 1
           ),
         Choice = lead(Choice)) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Gives us:

```
      ID Question Alternative Choice   X_1   X_2   X_3   X_4   X_5   X_6   X_7
   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1        1           1      2     2     2     1     1     2     1     1
 2     1        1           2      0     2     2     1     1     2     1     2
 3     1        2           1      1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1
 4     1        2           2      0     2     1     1     1     2     1     2
 5     1        3           1      2     2     1     2     1     1     2     1
 6     1        3           2      0     1     2     2     2     1     2     2
 7     1        4           1      2     1     1     1     1     2     1     1
 8     1        4           2      0     1     2     1     1     2     1     2
 9     1        5           1      1     2     1     2     2     1     2     1
10     1        5           2      0     2     1     1     1     2     1     1
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Question = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), Alternative = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2), Choice = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), X_1 = c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), X_2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1), X_3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), X_4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), X_5 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), X_6 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), X_7 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you Matt.
However, my dataset is much larger than the snippet I provided and therefore this answer (so far) isn't applicable to the entire dataset. It is not feasible for me to manually enter each choice into case_when statement.

Comment: If anything is unclear about my conditions then I am happy to elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

- df is the original choice data

---

```
 df <- data.frame(
      ID = c(1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1),
      Question = c(1,   1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5),
      Alternative = c(1,    2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2),
      Choice =  c(0,    1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0),
      X_1  =    c(2,    2,  1,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2),
      X_2 = c(2,    2,  1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1),
      X_3 = c(1,    1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  1),
      X_4 = c(1,    1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  2,  1),
      X_5 = c(2,    2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  2),
      X_6 = c(1,    1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  1),
      X_7 = c(1,    2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1)
      )
```

`df`

```
   ID   Question Alternative Choice X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 X_6 X_7
1   1        1           1      0   2   2   1   1   2   1   1
2   1        1           2      1   2   2   1   1   2   1   2
3   1        2           1      1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1
4   1        2           2      0   2   1   1   1   2   1   2
5   1        3           1      0   2   1   2   1   1   2   1
6   1        3           2      1   1   2   2   2   1   2   2
7   1        4           1      0   1   1   1   1   2   1   1
8   1        4           2      1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2
9   1        5           1      1   2   1   2   2   1   2   1
10  1        5           2      0   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
```

Create a new data set df2 with a new variable DepVar that recodes the Choice variable. (Or, you can ignore the df2 part, just modify the df itself)

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(DepVar = ifelse(Choice==1, Alternative, 0)) %>%
           arrange(ID, Question, -DepVar)
```

`df2`

```
   ID   Question Alternative Choice X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 X_6 X_7 DepVar
1   1        1           2      1   2   2   1   1   2   1   2      2
2   1        1           1      0   2   2   1   1   2   1   1      0
3   1        2           1      1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1      1
4   1        2           2      0   2   1   1   1   2   1   2      0
5   1        3           2      1   1   2   2   2   1   2   2      2
6   1        3           1      0   2   1   2   1   1   2   1      0
7   1        4           2      1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2      2
8   1        4           1      0   1   1   1   1   2   1   1      0
9   1        5           1      1   2   1   2   2   1   2   1      1
10  1        5           2      0   2   1   1   1   2   1   1      0
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort!
Unfortunately, the required format is fairly strict. I've tried your solution and it doesn't accept it. 
Perhaps I'm explaining it poorly. For reference, this link also (somewhat) discusses the required format of the data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85362/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-choicemodelr-rhiermnlrwmixture-in-r?rq=1

Comment: The Choice variable indicates which alternative has been chosen, but doesn't act as a dummy anymore. It now indicates the number of the variable chosen, in the first row of each question.

Comment: Not sure how may I be of help anymore. I just found this page discussing usage of ChoiceModelR: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Research_using_ChoiceModelR 
See the link to example data and code therein.